# How do I set css styles on my div with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a div that is colorized.

```js
let s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js";

document.head.appendChild(s);

let background = document.createElement("div");
background.id = "rwBackground";
document.body.appendChild(background);

let enabled = false;

$(function(){
  $("#rwBackground").css({
    "background-color": "#111",
    position: "fixed",
    height: document.body.innerHeight + "px",
    width: document.body.innerWidth + "px",
    top: "0px",
    left: "0px",
    filter: "blur(100px)"
  });
});
```

I tried putting "" outside of the CSS styles, but it doesn't seem to work.

I would check the body, and I can see it in there, but it has no styles.

If anyone could help me on this, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery before it has loaded. There's most likely an error in your console about `$` not being defined (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use jQuery before it has loaded.

You could use the techniques in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/283366) or you could move with the times and avoid jQuery entirely

```js
const background = document.createElement("div");
background.id = "rwBackground";

Object.assign(background.style, {
  backgroundColor: "#111",
  position: "fixed",
  height: "100%", // document.body.innerHeight + "px",
  width: "100%", // document.body.innerWidth + "px",
  top: "0px",
  left: "0px",
  filter: "blur(100px)"
});

document.body.appendChild(background);
```

FYI `innerHeight` and `innerWidth` are not properties of [HTMLBodyElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLBodyElement)